# How do I suppress IntelliJ's Authentication Required dialog from reappearing?

Tags: svn, authentication, version-control, intellij-idea, dialog

I access my Subversion server over VPN.

When the VPN is down, despite the fact that I'm not doing any kind of subversion operation (i.e., commit, check out, update) IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.2 (Build IC-133.696) keeps throwing up the Authentication Required dialog.

Of course, when I'm on VPN the dialog disappears, my problem is that when I need to work offline (i.e., traveling) this dialog keeps coming back!

I never had this issue in IntelliJ IDEA 12; so what's going on?

Why does IntelliJ 13 need authentication?

How do I get rid of this dialog so when I'm offline I can actually work more than a minute at a time before dismissing the dialog once again?

Note, I did find the "Version Control:Background:Changed on Server conflicts" option and disabled it, but the dialog keeps popping back up.

Comment: I'm using Subversion version 1.8.8 (r1568071) in case this is relevant.

Comment: I usually mark the project as not being a version controlled project for the duration of my non-vpn work.